# Installing Passenger for Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache2, passenger, redmine

I am new to ruby/rails.

I am trying to install Redmine but I am unable to get the application to start.

My installation consists of centos 6, apache, mysql, passenger.

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.3 (upgrade from 1.8.7)
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-02-22 patchlevel 392) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
      - ruby
      - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
      - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
      - /root/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
      - :update_sources => true
      - :verbose => true
      - :backtrace => false
      - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
  - https://rubygems.org/
```

Apache Config file:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19
PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin support@example.com
  ServerAlias redmine.example.com

  PassengerSpawnMethod smart
  PassengerPoolIdleTime 300
  RailsFrameworkSpawnerIdleTime 0
  PassengerMaxRequests 5000
  PassengerStatThrottleRate 5
  PassengerMinInstances 3
  RailsEnv production

  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/redmine/public
  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/html/redmine/public/>
    RackBaseURI /redmine
    Options -MultiViews   
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all      
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here are the errors I recieve.

```
[error] *** Passenger could not be initialized because of this error: Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because its executable (/usr/lib/phusion passenger/agents/PassengerWatchdog) does not exist. This probably means that your Phusion Passenger installation is broken or incomplete, or that your 'PassengerRoot' directive is set to the wrong value. Please reinstall Phusion   Passenger or fix your 'PassengerRoot' directive, whichever is applicable.
[Fri Apr 26 17:27:29 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 Phusion_Passenger/3.0.19 PHP/5.3.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Apr 26 17:27:33 2013] [error] [client 173.161.44.5] File does not exist: /var/www/html/redmine/public/index.html
[Fri Apr 26 17:27:34 2013] [error] [client 173.161.44.5] File does not exist: /var/www/html/redmine/public/index.html
[Fri Apr 26 17:27:35 2013] [error] [client 173.161.44.5] File does not exist: /var/www/html/redmine/public/index.html
[Fri Apr 26 17:27:37 2013] [error] [client 173.161.44.5] File does not exist: /var/www/html/redmine/public/redmine.html
```

Second Error:

```
[error] *** Passenger could not be initialized because of this error: Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because its executable (/usr/lib/phusion-passenger/agents/PassengerWatchdog) does not exist. This probably means that your Phusion Passenger installation is broken or incomplete, or that your 'PassengerRoot' directive is set to the wrong value. Please reinstall Phusion Passenger or fix your 'PassengerRoot' directive, whichever is applicable.
[Fri Apr 26 17:32:42 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 Phusion_Passenger/3.0.19 PHP/5.3.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Apr 26 17:32:50 2013] [error] [client 173.161.44.5] File does not exist: /var/www/html/redmine/public/redmine.html
[Fri Apr 26 17:32:52 2013] [error] [client 173.161.44.5] File does not exist: /var/www/html/redmine/public/redmine.html
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may have installed Phusion Passenger though APT too, and now your Apache has loaded two conflicting versions of Phusion Passenger. You should search through all your Apache config files and remove any config snippets pertaining to the loading of the version that was installed through APT (specifically, the LoadModule and PassengerRoot directives).

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 I had the exact same issue.  It was several issues, one being I ended up with multiple passengers installed.

```
#Remove old installs, just in case
gem uninstall passenger
apt-get uninstall libapache2-mod-passenger
#Reinstall
apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger
#Rebuild passenger module
passenger-install-apache2-module
#FOLLOW ALONG, apt-get things it tells you too
#Copy the snippet it leaves you at the end
#Paste snippet into your appropriate apache2 sites file
service apache2 restart
```

Now passenger is loading correctly